# custom amount of cells in each tableview group

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, tableview

How would I be able to customize the amount of cells in each tableview group? Basically, I need 2 cells in the first group, 4 cells in the second group, and one cell in the third. I can't seem to find anything, which is odd, unless I'm calling it the wrong thing. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0)
        return 2;
    else if (section == 1)
        return 4;
    else if (section == 2)
         return 1;
}
```

Comment: Question: how would I be able to: 1) insert any data; and 2) create an action for each cell (e.g.: cell 1 goes to another view controller, cell 2 pushes an action sheet, cell 3 has a UISwitch on the right side of the cell, etc.)

Comment: By the way, Thank you very much for helping me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: This *highly* depends on if you're using Storyboard and if you have access to prototype cells of ios5. This is a huge topic, your best bet would be to google for tutorials that meet your needs. Make sure to include information about the dependencies I've mentioned here

Answer (score 2):

Number of cells in each table **section** is specified in table's data source `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method. Somewhat dummy example for your case:

```
- (int) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView*)tableView{
    return 3;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    int numbers[] = {2,4,1};
    return numbers[section];
}
```